# Using images from other domains in wall posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When using the Open graph to post an image to someones wall, can the image be on a different domain than the domain in the app?

For example; If I am at www.joeswebsite.com, where the app on FB is set-up for, can I include a picture from www.wilmaswebsite.com when I make a wall post through open graph?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to since the only thing that opg does is turn a website into something easier searchable for facebook

> Facebook indexes Open Graph protocol markup found on pages shared in a member's social news feed. This markup also enhances social news feed stories generated by the Like button social plugin and Facebook Share.
>   Open Graph protocol markup turns webpages into objects within the Facebook social graph, increasing search exposure and uniquely classifying your site and story type within the social news feed.

i would just do a test run